# What's new in Jersey 1.5 version?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

There is any place I can see the Changelog for Jersey 1.5 in front of 1.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit;
Changelog is here

http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/tags/jersey-1.5/jersey/changes.txt?rev=4533